# dir_util.copy_tree won't print the files that it copies

Tags: python, windows

I'm using Python 2.6. I use the dir_util.copy_tree function to copy files, and I want to see which files are copied on the command line. However, it never prints them out, even when I specify verbose=1! Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(source, dest, verbose=1)
```

Comment: According to the documentation the return value of the copy_tree() function is a list of files copied.

Comment: @Mike I also looked at the return value, and it is None, even though I am DEFINITELY copying files over (I can watch them appear)

Comment: Not sure why. It works for me in Python 2.6. If you're curious let me know and I can post the steps I took as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `copy_tree` command uses `distutils.log` to write to your screen. In this case you need the `INFO` level.

So this should do the trick:

```
from distutils import log
log.set_verbosity(log.INFO)
log.set_threshold(log.INFO)
```

Note that it writes to `sys.stderr` for `WARN`, `ERROR` and `FATAL` and to `sys.stdout` for `DEBUG` and `INFO`.

---

In case newer versions implement the logging module you have to setup a logging config for it to work:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: I put your code into my module, and it still prints nothing. Am I supposed to attach the logger somehow? I can get log statements to print if I log myself...

Comment: For me in a standalone bit of code it worked straight away, but after further inspection of the `copy_tree` module it seems it doesn't use the default logging module. So... I'll modify my answer :)

Comment: interesting. So you're setting distutils' logging module to INFO in this example since it doesn't default to that correct? I'll try it soon and get back to you

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You can check the source here: https://bitbucket.org/carljm/python-distutils/src/48c42eeaee4410d76675b637bcd401b8919ff19a/log.py?at=default Initially it is set to `WARN`